# Sql Case Column 1 and Column same value

Tags: sql

I would like apply calculation in CASE Statement, but the result is not I'm expected and I'm not sure how to apply the query to filter date(depend on month). What is the problem with my query?? Please help... Thank you

this is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.SERVICE_CODE, 
       CASE 
           WHEN b.SERVICE_CODE IS NULL THEN a.AMT 
           ELSE  SUM (a.AMT) - SUM(b.AMT) 
       END AS TOTAL_AMT
 FROM 
     Table a
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Table b ON (a.SERVICE_CODE = b.SERVICE_CODE)
 WHERE  b.SERVICE_CODE >='3000' AND c.SERVICE_CODE >='3000'
```

Table a

```
Invoice_No               date          Service_code     Amt
001                     1/7/2014       6000             300
002                     1/8/2014       6003             700
003                     5/8/2014       6003             100
004                     10/8/2014      6005             1000
```

Table b

```
Credit_No                 date          Service_code     Amt
c100                     1/7/2014       6000             300
c200                     13/8/2014      6003             700
```

Desired output

```
Service_code              Total_Amt
6003                      100
6005                      1000
```

Thank you

Comment: You are using aggregate functions in one part of your `case` but not in the other... and you are not specifying the `group by` fields... I think that's inconsistent

Comment: `WHERE  b.SERVICE_CODE >='3000' AND c.SERVICE_CODE >='3000'`. Where did table `c` come from?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your query so that you always get the one-to-one relationship between your two tables. In this case I recommend you use a subquery where you group your amounts and LEFT JOIN it to your other table, like this. Also, if you need to filter it by a certain date range, just add the `where` clause to the subquery:

```
SELECT a.SERVICE_CODE, 
       CASE 
           WHEN b.SERVICE_CODE IS NULL THEN a.Amount 
           ELSE  a.Amount - b.AMT 
       END AS TOTAL_AMT
 FROM 
     (SELECT SERVICE_CODE, SUM(Amt) Amount
     FROM Tablea 
     WHERE date >= '2014-07-01' AND date < '2014-08-01'
     GROUP BY SERVICE_CODE) a
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Tableb b ON (a.SERVICE_CODE = b.SERVICE_CODE)
 WHERE  a.SERVICE_CODE >='3000' AND b.SERVICE_CODE >='3000'
```

Comment: what about the date? it was not mentioned in your original query. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: ok, I see now. You want to filter the date by and select some month

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a bit:

```
select service_code, tot_sum from (
    select a.service_code
         , sum(a.amt) - (select coalesce(sum(b.amt), 0) 
                         from b 
                         where a.SERVICE_CODE = b.SERVICE_CODE) as tot_sum 
    from a group by a.service_code
) as T 
where tot_sum <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with your `CASE SUM` statement, it should be the other way around: `Sum(Case ...`

Try this:

```
 SELECT a.SERVICE_CODE,
           SUM(
               CASE 
                   WHEN b.SERVICE_CODE IS NULL THEN 
                      a.AMT 
               ELSE  
                      a.AMT- b.AMT
               END
           ) AS TOTAL_AMT
     FROM 
         Table a
         LEFT OUTER JOIN Table b ON (a.SERVICE_CODE = b.SERVICE_CODE)
GROUP BY a.SERVICE_CODE
     WHERE  b.SERVICE_CODE >='3000' AND c.SERVICE_CODE >='3000'
```

Full working example, anyone can try:

```
SELECT 
    A.SERVICE_CODE, 
    SUM
    (
        CASE WHEN B.SERVICE_CODE IS NULL THEN 
            A.AMT
        ELSE
            A.AMT- B.AMT
        END 
    ) AS TOTAL
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS SERVICE_CODE, 101 AS AMT FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 1 AS SERVICE_CODE, 99  AS AMT FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 1 AS SERVICE_CODE, 96  AS AMT FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 1 AS SERVICE_CODE, 104 AS AMT FROM DUAL
) TABLE_A A --SAMPLE TABLE 1
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT NULL AS SERVICE_CODE, 201 AS AMT FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT NULL AS SERVICE_CODE, 199  AS AMT FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 1 AS SERVICE_CODE, 204  AS AMT FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 1 AS SERVICE_CODE, 99 AS AMT FROM DUAL
)TABLE_B B --SAMPLE TABLE 2
    ON A.SERVICE_CODE = B.SERVICE_CODE

GROUP BY A.SERVICE_CODE
```

Output:

[image]